# Why does ajax call cache form data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

The below code works perfect the first time it fires, BUT if I need to send a second time (login failed..) it re-sends the original form data even though new values are submitted...how do I reset and reload data..

I've already tried a ton of things including cache:false (which presumably only works for GET) and messing with the url to avoid browser caching...no luck so far. Pls help ;-)

```
function procLogin() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://www.lalala.com/lalala/auth.php?' + Math.random(),
        crossDomain: true,
        data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,

        success: function(response) {
            if (response.statusTFD == 'success') {
                alert("Success");
            } else if (response.statusTFD == 'error') {
                alert("Authentication Invalid. Please try again!");
            } else if (response.statusTFD.substring(0, 18) == 'Connection    Failed:' || response.statusTFD.substring(0, 6) == 'Error:') {
                alert(response.statusTFD);
            } else {
                alert("!¤#%¤!#" + response);
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            //alert(response.success);
            alert('Could not connect to the database' + error);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

The above is called with onsubmit:

```
<form id="loginForm" method="POST" onsubmit="procLogin()">
```

Comment: Are you using IE for testing? Even new versions of IE are notorious for caching XHR requests.

Edit - Ah I missed that you're already trying the Math.random() trick, so I'd have to investigate further.

Comment: How is `procLogin()` called ? Thanks

Comment: Don't use `async:false`

Comment: procLogin() is called with onsubmit: <form id="loginForm" method="POST" onsubmit="procLogin()">

Comment: unfortunately, removing `async:false` does not solve the problem. Thanks for your input though :-)

Comment: Are all browsers affected or a just a specific one?

Comment: All browsers are indeed affected - has been tested with IE, Chrome and FF..

Comment: Have you tried "contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: I have added contentType, but problem is not solved. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Just a little comment - note, that `success` and `error` properties are depracated since jQuery 1.8, I believe. In current versions `done`, `fail` and `always` chain methods are recommended. See [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more information. PS. I've seen this resolving many issues, in some kind of a strange way it may help with yours as well.

Comment: Hi Michal - good point. I have updated and although it has not solved the problem it probably has made the code a bit more future proof ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In JS -

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false,
        headers: {
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
        }
    });
```

In PHP

```
header('cache-control: no-cache');
```

Use both to avoid caching problem.

Comment: Hi Raj, thanks for your input. I tried your suggestion but adding the header to my php makes no difference- Adding it to the AJAX returns error...

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have come up with so far is to do `location.reload();` if the user/pw is not authenticated. In this case the login page is reloaded and Ajax call will receive the new values submitted in stead of the original/cached ones...Still interested in learning what is wrong with the code though, if anyone has an input..?

Thanks for all your help!